# Cron Job did not run

Tags: codeigniter, cron, cpanel

I am using codeigniter 3.1.3 with modular extensions. I have a command for a cron job but it does not seem to work in my cpanel. The cron job is supposed to run every half hour

```
 0,30   *   *   *   *   php-cli /home/username/public_html/index.php/module_name controller_name method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command

```
0,30   *   *   *   *   php /home/username/public_html/index.php/module_name controller_name method
```

Get rid of `defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed')` in the controller and any model that the controller is loading

You can read more about running from the command line from the codeigniter documentation

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/cli.html

Answer (score -1):

First 0,30 is a single parameter, so you need to add one more. Also you're not calling your Codeigniter function correctly. The standard syntax looks like this:

```
0,30   *   *   *   *   *  php-cli /home/username/public_html/index.php/module_name/controller_name/method_name parameters
```

I left in the 'module_name' segment of the of the URL even though I'm not sure too familiar with HMVC, and I've seen different structures in what little I have seen, so change the order of those if appropriate.